# How call WordPress shortcode inside function file

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I am trying to add shortcode to a new WooCommerce tab in the account section that I created in the functions file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_new-item_endpoint', 'add_new_item_content' );

/**
 * Add content to the new tab.
 *
 * @return  string.
 */
function add_new_item_content() {
    echo 'New Item Contents here!';
}
```

I need `echo do_shortcode('[Shortcode]');` to go where it says "New Item Contents here!" is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I need `echo do_shortcode('[Shortcode]');` to go where it says "New
> Item Contents here!" is there any way to do this?

Just put it there:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_new-item_endpoint', 'add_new_item_content' );

/**
 * Add content to the new tab.
 *
 * @return  string.
 */
function add_new_item_content() {
    echo do_shortcode('[Shortcode]');
}
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but that's all you need to do.

Comment: nah that worked thank you, I swear I tried that and it gave me a error when trying to save it.